# How to maintain an application that use the accelerometer sensor work correctly in lock-mode?

Tags: android, accelerometer

I have created a simple app that uses the accelerometer sensor to calculate the outside force then start a mp3 file. It seems to work well unless I turn screen off (or it automaticlly turns itself off) then it stops completely. How can i fix it. My code here, Thanks.

```
 private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private TextView textView;
private SensorManager sensorManager;
private Sensor accelerometerSensor;
private float maxf;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accelerometerSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometerSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if(event.sensor.getType() != Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
            return;
        }
        float x = event.values[0];
        float y = event.values[1];
        float z = event.values[2];
        float f =  Math.round(Math.abs(x*x + y*y + z*z));
        if (f>maxf ){ maxf =f;}
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("forrce:").append(f).append("\n");
        sb.append("MaxForce:").append(maxf).append("\n");
        textView.setText(sb.toString());

      if (maxf>150) {
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.b);
            mediaPlayer.start();
            maxf=1;
        }
   }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add on-lock **services**
[Reference][1]https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html
And use accelerometer in that particular activity...Hope it helps :)

Comment: I've put :`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />` to Manifest but it doesn't work

Comment: Services is different than a permission,services are meant to take the activity after it has been destroyed/If screen is locked etc. Example-: If you are a user of Truecaller they use services to display the name of the person who's calling you....
Permission asks the user to use certain aspects of their device.
Eg- Instagram will take permission to use your phone's camera.

Comment: I had given you the wrong link..please recheck the link I've given